# Изменение html

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть див в нем картинка, как с помощью jquery обернуть картинку  элементом <a>

```
  <div id="general">
     <img src="foto.png" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В jQuery для этого предназначен метод `wrap()`:

```
<script>
$("#general img").wrap("<a></a>");
</script>
```